# How to know when fespaces can be multiplied, added, subtracted etc

Tags: freefem++

In the examples I see fespaces being very often multiplied and added, such as in this example:
https://doc.freefem.org/tutorials/timeDependentStokes.html
However when I do the same I very often get the following error message such as from this code:

```
fespace Uh(Th,P1);
Uh Ex, Ext;
Uh Exold;
Uh Extold;
Uh Ey,Eytold, Eyt;
Uh fx, fy;

problem Maxwell([Ex,Ey],[fx,fy]) = int2d(Th)(
    (dx(Ex)+dy(Ey))*(dx(fx)+dy(fy))
) - int2d(Th)(
    (dx(Ey) - dy(Ex))*(dx(fy) - dx(fy))
) - int2d(Th)(
    mu0*epsilon0*(10*exp(-30*y))*(
         (Ex*fx + Ey*fy)-(Extold*fx - Eytold*fy)
    
)) + on(source,Ex = sin(8*x),Ey = 0);
```

```
error operator *  <10LinearCombI7MGauche4C_F0E>, <10LinearCombI7MGauche4C_F0E>
```

So how do I know when they can and cannot be multiplied, added etc...?